# How do you mange to document api response when using prisma and nestjs?

Tags: swagger, nestjs, prisma

Do have an idea about how you can document quickly an api response when using nestjs and prisma.

let's say I have

I have this controller

```
  @Get('/user-profile')
  @ApiOkResponse({ type: UserProfileResponse })
  getUserProfile(@payLoad() payLoad: JwtPayload): Promise<UserProfileResponse> {
    return this.userService.getUserProfile(payLoad);
  }
```

This service

```
  async getUserProfile(payLoad: JwtPayload): Promise<UserProfileResponse> {
    return await this.prisma.user.findUnique({
      where:{id:payLoad.userId},
      include: {
        address : { select: {city:true,}}     

      }
    })

  }

export class UserProfileResponse {
    id: string;
    username: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    address : AddressCity;
}

class AddressCity {
    city: string;
}
```

I will need to create a DTO to specify the response each time .Whith this example It's not a big deal but when we have deeply nested response object It became realy time consuming.

Do have like an idean to speed up this process  ?